# iSCSI Multipath to block device on zfs pool in ubuntu

Tags: linux, zfs, iscsi, multipath

I have succesfuly set up zfs pool, created block on it , and created iscsi target. The target is visible from esx host and i can us it as datastore.

steps i did:

- zpool create tank raidz2 sdb sdc sdd raidz2 sde sdf sdg
- zfs create -o compression=off -o dedup=off -o volblocksize=32K -V 1500G tank/datastore-ssd
- than i used targetcli to run iscsi target on datastore-ssd

Now i want to add multipath in case of san failure. The problem is that i don't see this device . I am trying to use dm-multipath package and what i need is wwid of device to configure multipath. But i cannot find this wwid. I even don't see this block dev i created as dev. Maybe i am wrong at all and should do it in diffirent way - no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (NFS is so much better for this!)

Comment: Thanks, I have switched to NFS and it works like a charm.

Comment: If you are using iSCSI, your "path" is an ethernet network. So multipath in this case means that you provide different ethernet paths to your iSCSI target (maybe using different NICs on the storage box connected to your storage network switch, or maybe using completely redundant ethernet switches and NICs). So, ZFS has nothing to do with multipath, this is a matter of iSCSI and networking config.